# CSS ~ Hover not working to change external class

Tags: html, css

I have two classes, `.growImage` and `.footer`. When you hover over a div that contains the image, the image follow the following CSS...

```
.growImage:hover {
transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

and it works... but below that CSS is this...

```
.growImage:hover ~ #footer {
height:1000px;
}
```

and it is supposed to enlarge the height of the footer as well but it doesn't. Please note I have tried converting both of them to ID'S (#example) and both of them to regular classes (.example), that didn't work. I tried add `important!` to the changing attribute, that also didn't work. The most confusing thing is, I started a new html webpage and made blank divs that contained nothing and minimal attributes and the code above worked on those so why isn't it working on the current webpage I am working on?

Here is the HTML...

```
<div class="growImage"><img src="images/familyTree.jpg" width="333px" height="250px"/></div>

<div class="footer">
This is the footer.</div>
```

Here is the CSS...

```
.footer{
height:50px;
width:960px;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
background-color:white;
color:black;
padding-top:27px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
float:left;
}

.growImage:hover{
transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
transform-origin:0 0;
}

.growImage:hover ~ .footer {
height:1000px;
}
```

Sorry I should have included this before but this is the rest of the CSS...

```
#container{
height:920px;
width:960px;
background-color:#000;
margin:auto;
display: block;
float: none;
}
#header{
height:100px;
width:960px; 
float:left;
background-color:white;
}
#navigation{
height:100px; 
width:660px; 
font-size:30px;
color:black;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
float:left;
background-color:white;
}
#logo{
height:100px;
width:300px; 
float:left;
background-color:white;
}
#body{
height:770px;
width:920px;
background-color:#0081c3;
color:white;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-top:20px;
float:left;
}
#footer{
height:50px;
width:960px;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
background-color:white;
color:black;
padding-top:27px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
float:left;
}
html{
/*background-color:#ffd636;*/
background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
}
a:Link{ 
text-decoration:none; 
}
a:visited{
text-decoration:none; 
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:none; 
}
a:active{
text-decoration:bold; 
}
img{
   border-style: none;
}
.buttonBorder{
width:165px;
height:100px;
padding-top:31px;
color:white;
float:left;
border-left: 1px solid white;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color:#ffd636;
}
.buttonSelected{
width:165px;
height:100px;
padding-top:31px;
color:white;
float:left;
border-left: 1px solid white;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color:#ed3133;
}
.buttonBorder:hover{
color:#ffd636;
background-color:white;
}
td{
width:150px;    
}
.growImage:hover{
transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
transform-origin:0 0;
}
.growImage:hover ~ .footer {
height:1000px;
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine and does what you expect it to. There maybe some other selectors elsewhere in your CSS file (with higher specificity) that are over-riding it.

Comment: @Harry would you like me to update the original post and display the rest of the CSS?

Comment: Go ahead, include your full CSS so that we an see where the problem is.

Comment: @Harry sorry it took a while to put 4 spaces in front of every line but it's up now

Comment: There's a line in the container class which isn't supposed to be there but I took it out and it made no difference to the issue at hand `display: block;`

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help @Harry

Comment: There are quite a lot of differences between your HTML and the CSS (maybe a result of your trial and error). The class name is `growImage` but the one in selector is `.enlargeImage`. Footer is a class in HTML but is an id selector in CSS. Those differences aside, your code still works. Maybe it is better for you to create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I just fixed the enlargeImage and growImage, it still don't work, that was my fault with the copying across to this site. Ok I will make jsFiddle. BRB

Comment: Try this, http://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/xbdbpkez/1/#&togetherjs=cB2v2b6Kw7 I wanted the body to grow actually to accommodate for the image becoming larger

Comment: Poor soul, @PleaseHelp next time after you paste code, select the code and hit the { } button above the editing window to mark the selected text as code.

Comment: haha thank you @tokamak

Comment: GO to this link http://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/xbdbpkez/1/ and try to get the body to grow in height to accommodate the image when it grows on the hover

Comment: @PleaseHelp: Why is your initial question and the fiddle so different? In the question you were trying to change footer on hovering the image but here in fiddle you are trying to change the `#body` while hovering the image. For that your current selector won't work. You should go through CSS selectors more. What you are currently using is a sibling selector whereas `#body` is the parent of the `.growImage`.

Comment: It's because I thought if I made the footer the target to grow, the change would be more noticable therefore I would be aware that it was actually working. I just didn't want to miss the fact that it was working. I apologise that was my fault. But I do  want the body to grow.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried with both id and class . it doesn't shows any problem.
>   But you should implement like this because css `scale` is not the best idea because its will overlap siblings elements. try to use height: ( If u want to see full image when hovering )or set parent element overflow as hidden
>   Check here

```css
#footer{
height:50px;
width:960px;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
background-color:white;
color:black;
padding-top:27px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
float:left;
}

/* This rule added just for testing purpose only */
 div#footer {
 background:green;
   transition-duration:.5s;
 
 }
/* overflow avoid overflow of child elements when hovering */
#growImage{
  overflow:hidden;
}
#growImage:hover img{
transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
transform-origin:0 0;
  transition-duration:.5s;
}

#growImage:hover ~ #footer {
height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="growImage">
  <img src="http://devgene.com/wp-content/themes/devgene/assets/img/tba-mobile.png" width="333px" height="250px"/>
</div>

<div id="footer">
This is the footer.</div>
```

Comment: Saying that there is no problem is not really an answer. This could have and should have been a comment.

Comment: It doesn't grow in height at all?

Comment: both #footer and #growImage height is increasing when hovering.

Comment: I actually need # body to grow I just explained that in the comments ~ sorry. Paranoia got the best of me

Comment: The snippet when run, enlarges the image but the footer doesn't change in height by a single pixel???????

Comment: fixed it .Edited my answer .Scaling is not the best idea because its will overlap siblings elements. try to use height:  ( If u want to see full image when hovering )or  set parent element overflow as hidden

Comment: Where is the code for it because it does work now, PS: I don't know how to use hidden or overflow @ddllr

Comment: It works in the snippet but not when applied to my webpage

Comment: Its should work .... may be some other problem ..... Post your webpage link here ........

Comment: `overflow:hidden` [Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) : The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible . It is used in my answer.

Comment: I have been very busy haven't tried anything yet? Sorry @ddllr